# What is the origin of the Lunar Module in the US Space and Rocket Center in Huntsville, AL?

Tags: apollo-program, history, lunar-module, museum-exhibits

I recently had a chance to visit the US Space and Rocket Center. While I was there, I saw a lunar module. It is very clear that the ascent portion is a mock-up, but the decent portion looks real, although it seems to be smaller than the one in the Smithsonian (Could just be because it is in a corner, the Smithsonian one you can walk around pretty good). I've seen mention on the internet that the descent stage was a [test article](https://www.roadsideamerica.com/story/10807), although I have carefully [searched the lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_Lunar_Module#Lunar_modules_produced) and not seen any mention of this. Any idea as to what the origin of this test vehicle was? Thanks!

Comment: Will try and get a picture soon, hopefully tomorrow, but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an engineering test mockup.

> This model incorporates an engineering model of the Descent Stage (used at MSFC, designers of the Lunar Rover, for studies and fit checks) with a fabricated Ascent stage (note the lack of detail in the hatchway area compared to some other LM images)

https://www.americanspacecraft.com/pages/lunarmod/msfc.html

Comment: Thanks! Been driving me crazy trying to get the scoop on it.

Comment: The Saturn V there with the V-2 lying at its base is mind-blowing. Also love the Shuttle Centaur and the MPTA. Great museum.

Comment: Was walking underneath it all morning long. It's pretty insane, to say the least!

Comment: Also, Shuttle Centaur sadly is no longer there... It seems it has ended up in Ohio.

Comment: Wow, glad I got to see & photograph it. But it seems fair, Lewis did do all the hydrogen stuff.

Comment: Is the serial number of this engineering model known?

Comment: @DrSheldon I have nothing about it other than what's at *The Field Guide to American Spacecraft*.